# Play framework Route case insensitive

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

We are currently working on Play 2.5.x

We wanted to achive case insensitive routing to be done. Say for example

**GET   /via/v1/organizations   http.organizationApi()**

In the URL we wanted to achive

**http://localhost:9000/abc/v1/organizations**

**http://localhost:9000/ABC/V1/OrganIZations**

Is the a way to achive this bu using regular expression? Can some one point to or provide me an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015902/play-framework-2-2-1-case-insensitive-routing

Comment: @MipH have seen the post earlier. I am looking for some regular expression to handle this one. May be I can upate the question on what exactly I need. Thank you

Comment: I think you may be interested to read this: https://jazzy.id.au/2013/05/08/advanced_routing_in_play_framework.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a request handler to make the URL case insensitive. In this case, the following handler will just convert the url to lowercase, so in your routes the url should be defined in lowercase:

```
import javax.inject.Inject

import play.api.http._
import play.api.mvc.RequestHeader
import play.api.routing.Router

class MyReqHandler @Inject() (router: Router, errorHandler: HttpErrorHandler,
                   configuration: HttpConfiguration, filters: HttpFilters
          ) extends DefaultHttpRequestHandler(router, errorHandler, configuration, filters) {

  override def routeRequest(request: RequestHeader) = {
    val newpath = request.path.toLowerCase
    val copyReq = request.copy(path = newpath)
    router.handlerFor(copyReq)
  }
}
```

And in `application.conf` reference it using:

```
# This supposes MyReqHandler.scala is in your project app folder
# If it is in another place reference it using the correct package name
# ex: app/handlers/MyReqHandler.scala --> "handlers.MyReqHandler"
play.http.requestHandler = "MyReqHandler"
```

Now, if you have a route define to "/persons/create", whatever case combination will work (ex: "/PeRsOns/cREAtE")

There are two caveats though:

- You can only use this with Scala actions. If your routes file references a Java controller method, you will get an odd exception:

  ```
  [error] p.c.s.n.PlayRequestHandler - Exception caught in Netty
  scala.MatchError: Right((play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$14$$anon$3@22d56da6,play.api.DefaultApplication@67d7f798)) (of class scala.util.Right)
  ```

  If this is your case you can find more info [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/A0rCbXVX_Gw)
- If your url have parameters, those will also be transformed. For example, if you have a route like this

  ```
  GET /persons/:name/greet       ctrl.Persons.greet(name: String)
  ```

  a call to "/persons/JohnDoe/greet" will be transformed to "/persons/johndoe/greet", and your `greet` method will receive "johndoe" instead of "JohnDoe" as parameter. Note that this does not apply to query string parameters.
  Depending in your use case, this can be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

with play 2.8, answer above is not working. the play api has changed so I pasted my code here.

```
class CaseInsensitive @Inject()(router: Router, errorHandler: HttpErrorHandler, configuration: HttpConfiguration, filters: EssentialFilter*)
extends DefaultHttpRequestHandler(new DefaultWebCommands, None, router, errorHandler, configuration, filters){

override def routeRequest(request: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {
  val target = request.target;
  val newPath = target.path.toLowerCase

  val newTarget = request.target.withPath(newPath)
  val newRequest = request.withTarget(newTarget);

  router.handlerFor(newRequest)
}
```

}