# Optional parameter with url rewriting in play 2.4

Tags: playframework, url-rewriting, java-8, optional-parameters, playframework-2.4

I want to use the optional parameter in play 2.4 java. After reading [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaRouting#Optional-parameters), I add the following routes:

```
GET  /api/users/:page  controllers.EmployeeController.getUsers(page:Int,pageSize:Int ?= 10)
```

I want the page size to be optional in this url. The url I can access are:

```
/api/users/1
/api/users/1?pageSize=5
```

But the problem is that I want to use the second url like:

```
/api/users/1/5
```

Which currently gave me action not found.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

**Note**: I don't want to create a separated url as @Salem mentioned. I want to use this single url in routes file.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a second mapping to the same controller (this supposes you want to use "10" as the pageSize value if none is provided)

```
GET     /api/users/:page              controllers.EmployeeController.getUsers(page:Int,pageSize:Int = 10)
GET     /api/users/:page/:pageSize    controllers.EmployeeController.getUsers(page:Int,pageSize:Int)
```

Note that the second parameter if `getUsers` is not optional anymore

Comment: Thanks but I forgot to mention that I dont want to create new route. Is there any other way?

Comment: I don't think so. You can try to write a filter like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38873541/1205368) to overwrite that specific url, but that will not work with Java controllers without some work. Also is a little overkill. If you have Nginx/Apache/etc in front of Play you can rewrite the url there...

Comment: @silentprogrammer what is avoiding you of creating another route??

Comment: @silentprogrammer Have you found a way to do what you needed?

Comment: @salem not yet but I think I should go with your approach as there is no other solution to this.